# (MFC) CListBox -> Edit Item in List?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently using the CListBox Control for MFC. Is it possible to retain the data inside the List Item but edit it, without deleting then re-adding it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by extending CListBox. Check out this [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CEditableListBox.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this, unfortunately.

Even the native list box class doesn't provide any way to edit an entry, without removing and inserting.

The best you can do is extending the `CListBox` class, either by sub-classing or deriving from it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way (if possible, sure), is replacing CListBox with CListCtrl